# how to return IEnumerable<String> with linq. Getting Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want the query to give me back a `NotificationConfiguration` and also an `IEnumerable<string>` (which I will later transform to a single string using SB). Once the query gives me back those two items I will transform it using a constructor in my view model so I can properly display all the data using a DataTable. The answer I am looking for maybe very specific but I need to understand why I'm getting the subquery error when I want it to return an `IEnumerable<string>` and how to fix it. Also please note... according to the .net docs the code should be handing my back an `IEnumerable<string>` but for some reason its still crashing. Here is the relevant code samples again:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(DataTableRequest requestedData)
    {
        using (this.dataStore.Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            return this.dataStore.Query<NotificationConfiguration>()
                          .TableRange(requestedData, p => new NotificationConfigurationViewModel(p,  p.Events.Select(x => x.Code) ?? null));
        }
    }
```

.

```
    public NotificationConfigurationViewModel(NotificationConfiguration notification , IEnumerable<string> events)
{
    Contract.Requires(notification != null);

    this.notification = notification;
    this.events = events;
}
```

.

```
[Display(Name = "Events")]
public virtual string EventTypeCodes
{
    get
    {
        var codes = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var item in this.events)
        {
           codes.Append(item + ",");
        }

        return codes.ToString().TrimEnd(',');
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the query actually defined? You're comparing a field or value to a SELECT that produces more than one value.

Comment: As a side point you can reduce your code with [string.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) return string.Join(",", this.events)